# Creating a get request using fetch - only options is send

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, request, http-get, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a get request using Fetch. The request looks like this:

```
fetch('https://requestb.in/14ikb6j1', {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token token=xxxxx'
  }});
```

If I make this request to my own server, it fails on the options request every time. I cannot figure out why.

If I make this request to requestbin, there is an options request first. However, after receiving the options response, the actual get request is never made.

This is what requestbin received:

```
OPTIONS /14ikb6j1

HEADERS

Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Host: requestb.in
Total-Route-Time: 0
Via: 1.1 vegur
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
Cf-Ipcountry: NL
Cf-Ray: 36edd35d1cad2b28-AMS
Cf-Connecting-Ip: 37.153.231.90
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Connect-Time: 1
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
X-Request-Id: 69b120c1-0f18-454b-a7fd-91f082252a06
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: http://localhost:9000
```

This is what chrome logs:

[image: chrome dev tools]

---

The strangest thing is, I get a `200 - OK` status as result. The console however, still logs this:

> Fetch API cannot load https://requestb.in/14ikb6j1. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>   :9000/#/branching:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

But if I make this request using Postman it does work:[image: postman request]

```
GET /14ikb6j1
HEADERS

Cf-Ipcountry: NL
Cf-Ray: 36eddb797ebf7223-AMS
Authorization: Token token=xxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Total-Route-Time: 0
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connection: close
Cf-Connecting-Ip: 37.153.231.90
Connect-Time: 0
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Postman-Token: 57486701-6f9a-4aab-be1b-776f0d376920
Accept: */*
Host: requestb.in
X-Request-Id: 73a7a35e-0d89-41fd-b760-2aa952349871
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

How can I make this get request with authentication headers work?

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` for a GET request. Is that right?

Comment: @Forivin Sorry you're right. Updated, removing those content type headers doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a CORS problem. The server you are seinding the request to doesn't allow requests from a different domain. 
Check your browser console and look for errors. You might find somehting like this:

> Fetch API cannot load https://requestb.in/14ikb6j1. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: But why would my postman request work if the cors is disabled?

Comment: Because postman doesn't have a domain. It acts as if it's a normal user opening a website. As a browser extension postman gets these sort of privileges, that websites cannot obtain by themselves. It's a simple security feature built into browsers to prevent website A from communicating with website B, unless website B is okay with it.